# List and justified text

Tags: lists, indentation

I'd like to indent every line of a paragraph but the first one. I found a solution here ([Indent all but first lines of paragraph.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2787/indent-all-but-first-lines-of-paragraph)) and I use the approach with the adjusted list. The only problem is, the length of the lines is not similar.

I have to insert a bibliography manually and this seems to be the best way to tackle the indent problem. But contrary to the standard bibliography, where every line has the same length, the lengths differ, which is not really nice. Is it possible to adjust the (hang)list command so that I get what I want?

edit:
The problem has been solved, more or less. I use the ragged2e package and at the beginning of the list I use "\justifying". URLs and some longer words cause still problems. Any recommendations?

Comment: [`\hangindent`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236898/11604)